# Does the ES7 decorator spec require descriptors to have an `initializer` method

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-2016

Using Babel to transpile the following es7 code:

```
let obj = {
  @decorate
  prop: 10
}

let decorate = ( object, propertyName, desc ) => desc
```

When `decorate` is called, the property descriptor `desc` contains a method named `initializer`, that returns the value of `obj.prop` when executed.

Is the `initializer` method part of the es7 Decorator specification, or is this purely a side effect of Babel converting to es5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> es7 Decorator specification

Notice there is neither ES7 yet nor a specification for decorators. There's a *draft*, a harmony proposal, for how the language may be extended.

> When `decorate` is called, the property descriptor `desc` contains a method named `initializer`

That's a bit odd. From the [current proposal](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/be51e9e0431772218e30691e243287502ec749c1/README.md) I would have expected that the decorator is always called with the property descriptor for that property, which would be

```
{value: 10, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

for your example. However, the examples in the draft do only outline decorators for methods (and accessor properties), both on classes and object literals, but not for value properties.

> Is the initializer method part of the Decorator proposal?

Not currently, but there is a [INITIALIZER_INTEROP.md](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators/blob/master/INITIALIZER_INTEROP.md) file in their repository which outlines interoperability of decorators with the `PropertyInitialisers` from the [class properties proposal](https://gist.github.com/jeffmo/054df782c05639da2adb) (which is an unfinished draft, but already implemented in babel, as well). It does indeed use static decorators which are given descriptors with an `initializer` function that would be evaluated to initialise the instance property in (before) the constructor.

> is this purely a side effect of Babel converting to es5?

Not really. [IMO it's just a bug](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2005), probably stemming from how babel transpiles class properties, which makes them look the same as value properties on an object literal.

Comment: Thanks, as I expected. Safe to assume that you cannot rely on `initializer` as a method to return the value

Comment: I think it would be save to assume that an `initializer` always returns the value, but in fact you indeed cannot rely on anything from babel's experimental features.

Answer (score 1):

The `initializer` function mostly makes sense if you consider the [proposal-class-fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) TC39 proposal.

Consider the following code:

```
class C {
  prop = {};
}

const a = new C()
const b = new C()

console.log(a.prop === b.prop)
```

You would expect the output to be `false`.

For that reason, the "value" of the property cannot be stored as a static `value`, but must instead be encoded as a function that returns a new value (here, an empty object) every time.

That code gets transpiled to something equivalent to:

```
class C {
    constructor () {
        const propName = 'prop'
        const propDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.constructor.prototype, propName)
        this[propName] = propDesc.initializer.call(this)
    }
}
```

This also allows you to reference `this` while declaring other instance variables (still in the context of that proposal):

```
class C {
    entries = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
    count = this.entries.length;
}
```

Since `class C` is basically syntactic sugar for writing `C.prototype`, decorators on class properties, are actually the same as decorators on object properties (the object being the prototype in this case).

The `initializer` pattern allows for a single way of writing decorators in both these cases.